# GRUB2 chainloading a loop device

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I've got a USB stick with many ISO files of various operating systems, currently GRUB is configured on this stick to load them as loopback and run them directly, however for one of them (a Windows 10 install iso) I need to load the iso and do a chainloading, this is the current menuentry:

```
menuentry "Windows 10 64bit" --class windows {
    loopback loop /windows-10-64bit.iso
    set root=loop
    chainloader +1
}
```

however, it always says `not a valid root device`, I've tried several ways to tell that `loop` is the root, but apparently it doesn't accept it. Is there a way to do this differently?

Answer (score 1):

The bootloader on the iso would not know how to fetch the rest of itself from an iso file on another file system, so even if grub didn't complain, it wouldn't work.

Which is maybe why grub complains.

If the bootloader on the iso is multiboot compliant, AND if it will be able to look on your file system to find the iso and continue booting from there, THEN maybe you could use the grub2 multiboot command to help.

But I doubt that windows can do that.